# Why does the Feynman sprinkler rotate in one direction only?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics

I asked a question earlier about an emptying balloon is space. There was a comparison made with the world famous Feynman sprinkler. So I looked it up. In [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_sprinkler#:%7E:text=A%20Feynman%20sprinkler%2C%20also%20referred,and%20remarkably%20long%2Dlived%20debate.) the Feynman sprinkler is discussed.

[image]

"Illustration 153a from Ernst Mach's Mechanik (1883). When the hollow rubber ball is squeezed, air flows in the direction of the short arrows and the wheel turns in the direction of the long arrow. When the rubber ball is released, the direction of the flow of the air is reversed but Mach observed "no distinct rotation" of the device.""

Feynman considered a water version immersed in a bath with water. The remarkable thing is that the sprinkler only rotates in one direction, namely if the water (or air) is pressed out. If it is "inhaled" no rotation comes into play. Only a small initial motion is seen. Clearly the situations are not each other's time inversions. Still, it's strange why the sprinkler not rotates in both directions.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282179/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/281788/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74240/123208